# How to fix this broken Dynamic Paint in Blender 3.2?

Tags: dynamic-paint

I am working with a very simple scene in Dynamic Paint in Blender. There is a canvas and a brush. I am trying to create ripples. It is working perfectly in version 3.1.2 and any version below that. But in version 3.2 the display is completely wrong. I have attached several screenshots below to describe the problem. It seems that Dynamic Paint is broken in 3.2 or I am missing some basic stuff. Can anyone please help me to rectify this in 3.2?

As you can see below, in version 3.2 the ripples are created correctly when we view it in the wireframe view mode. But in the solid view, the surface does not show the ripples. Even if we bake & render the scene, the output is same as it shows in the viewport i.e. ripples are missing.

The blend file is also attached for your reference. Thanks in advance for any help anyone can provide.

[image]

**Version 3.1.2 Wireframe view mode: Ripples are visible**

[image: Version 3.1.2 Wireframe view mode: Ripples are visible]

**Version 3.1.2 Solid view mode: Ripples are visible**

[image: Version 3.1.2 Solid view mode: Ripples are visible]

I have saved the file and opened it in Blender 3.2 version. The ripples are visible as expected in the Wireframe view mode. But they are now missing in the solid view mode (and also in render). This is really surprising! How to fix this?

**Version 3.2 Wireframe view mode: Ripples are visible**

[image: Version 3.2 Wireframe view mode: Ripples are visible]

**Version 3.2 Solid view mode: Ripples are NOT visible**

[image: Version 3.2 Solid view mode: Ripples are NOT visible]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I don't know why this is happening, maybe the normals aren't being recalculated and maybe there's an option somewhere for that, i don't know. But i can see the waves if i put a *Geometry Nodes* modifier after the *Dynamic Paint* modifier with the following node tree:

[image]

It doesn't modify the mesh, since the selection input for the *Extrude Mesh* node is always false.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. At least it now works. But following this clue, I discovered that we can do many other things as well, and simpler than this, to get the things work. For example, we can add a displace modifier with strength 0.01 or a bevel modifier with amount 0.01 (after the dynamic paint modifier) and the ripples display correctly without much distortion. But best is to add a simple deform modifier with angle or factor as zero. It won't change anything but the ripples will display perfectly. This has to be definitely a bug in 3.2 I am sure!